# Why will this image not stay in the div id?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="admid">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/SNP_2922296_en_v0" /></a>
</div>

#admid {
  height: 80px;
  width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

If you have anything to add let me know please. I am trying to learn by doing. eeekk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#admid {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#admin img {
    width: 100%;
}
```